# ‎Right now, I am filing this insurance application on behalf of you. So, I need your confirmation (on the matter) - do I need "on the matter" here?

Tags: meaning, prepositional-phrases

Example 1

> ‎Whenever I'm talking about a controversial topic, I change my tone and pause a little bit. I want to make sure I have my listener's agreement .

Example 2

> Whenever I'm talking about a controversial topic I change my tone and pass a little bit. I want to make sure I have my listeners agreement **on the topic.**

Example 3

> ‎Right now, I am filing this insurance application on behalf of you. So, I need your confirmation.

Example 4

> Right now I'm filing this insurance application on behalf of you. So I need your confirmation **on this matter.**

My question is if the context is very clear, do I have to add adjective preposition phrases like Examples 2 and 4?

Comment: Probably what you mean is *I need your **signature*** (somewhere on the form there might be something he can sign to indicate that you have authority to fill it in on his behalf). It's irrelevant whether you include ***on this matter***, which doesn't add anything at all to the meaning.

Comment: As @FumbleFingers did, you’d sound more idiomatic if you put it in terms of filling out the application “on your behalf,” rather than “on behalf of you,” which sounds a bit clumsy.

Comment: It depends if it's clear from the rest of the passage. It doesn't hurt to repeat yourself though.

Comment: Example 1: a more natural-sounding expression and one easier to perceive by the speaker would be **my listener's attention**. Example 3: as other users have commented **on your behalf** is the idiomatic phrase. There is no grammatical reason, it just is. Saying *on behalf **of you*** sounds odd  whereas "*on my /your/his/her /their behalf*" does not [sound odd].

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the additional phrases in 2 and 4. It is obvious what the sentence refers to with regards to your question.

Comment: We don't do copy editing on this site. If someone makes mistakes in their writing but doesn't ask about it, please don't take it upon your self to correct them or provide advice. If we did that, given the people who are asking most of the questions, the site would be mostly filled with corrections and comment wars about those corrections. Thanks for the effort though!